# What $x$ satisfies $3^{4x}\cdot 9^6 = 81^8$?

Tags: logarithms, exponentiation

> What $x$ satisfies $3^{4x}\cdot 9^6 = 81^8$?

I reckon it is possible to rearrange bases $3$ and $9$ to $81$, but I don't know how.
Which rules apply here?

Comment: Start with $9=3^2$ and $81=9^2$

Comment: And then set the exponents equal.

Comment: Even if the exponents didn't match up nicely., like if this was $3^{4x}\cdot\color{red}{7}^6=81^8$ instead, you could still get this using logarithms... things just might not nicely simplify.  You could move things which don't have variables to one side first, $3^{4x}=\dfrac{81^8}{7^6}$ and then take the logarithm... doesn't even matter which logarithm.  I'll use the natural log to highlight this... $\ln(3^{4x})=\ln\left(\dfrac{81^8}{7^6}\right)$ and so $4x\ln(3)=\ln\left(\dfrac{81^8}{7^6}\right)$ and so $x = \dfrac{1}{4\ln(3)}\cdot\ln\left(\dfrac{81^8}{7^6}\right)$

Answer (score 2):

$$3^{4x}\cdot 3^{12}=3^{32}$$

Thus

$$4x+12=32$$

$$x=5$$